# how to display retrived form from ajax next to respective row of table

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have problem in displaying retrived data from ajax next to respective row, it is display after table but i want to display it after that particular row and rest of row will be hide.
here is my code. response comes from ajax in one form that is fine so i here only post my ajax file and data table where i want to display.

```
<?php include("inc/header.php"); ?>
<!-- START OF MAIN CONTENT -->
<div class="mainwrapper">
    <div class="mainwrapperinner">

    <?php include("inc/mainleft.php"); ?>

  <div class="maincontent noright">
    <div class="maincontentinner">

        <ul class="maintabmenu">
                <li class="current"><a href="index.php">Regular Booking</a></li>
                <li><a href="dashboardcorporate.php">Corporate Booking</a></li>
                <li><a href="dashboardpersonal.php">Personal Booking</a></li>
                <li><a href="dashboardtopup.php">Topup Booking</a></li>
      </ul><!--maintabmenu-->



             <div class="content2">
                            <div class="contenttitle radiusbottom0">
                <h2 class="table"><span>RegularBooking Table</span></h2>
            </div><!--contenttitle-->


          <?php if($_GET['msg']=="update") { ?>
         <div class="notification msgsuccess" id="update" style="display:block;">
                    <a class="close"></a>
                   <p>Your Changes were <strong>Successfully</strong> Done! </p>
                    </div>
               <?php } ?>     


               <?php if($_GET['msg']=="mail") { ?>
         <div class="notification msgsuccess" id="update" style="display:block;">
                    <a class="close"></a>
                   <p>Your Job is <strong>Successfully</strong> Dispatched! </p>
                    </div>
               <?php } ?>   

                <?php if($_GET['msg']=="sorry") { ?>
         <div class="notification msgerror">
                    <a class="close"></a>
                    <p style="background:#FAD5CF">Sorry Your job is not Dispatched Please select active Driver!</p>
                </div>
               <?php } ?>







               <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" class="stdtable">

               <tr>
               <td>
               <img src="images/bluedot.png" class="imgg"  />&nbsp;<strong>New</strong>
               </td> 
               <td>
               <img src="images/reddot.png" class="imgg" />&nbsp;<strong>Cancelled</strong>
               </td>
               <td>
               <img src="images/yellowdot.png" class="imgg" />&nbsp;<strong>Confirmed</strong>
               </td>
               <td>
               <img src="images/browndot.jpg" class="imgg" />&nbsp;<strong>Pending</strong>
               </td>
               <td>
               <img src="images/blackdot.png" class="imgg" />&nbsp;<strong>Posponed</strong>
               </td>
               <td>
               <img src="images/greendot.png"  class="imgg"/>&nbsp;<strong>Confirmed Operator</strong>
               </td>
                <td>
               <img src="images/greendot.png"  class="imgg"/>&nbsp;<strong>Confirmed Driver</strong>
               </td>

               </tr>
               </table>






            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="stdtable" id="dyntable">
                <colgroup>
                    <col class="con0" />
                    <col class="con1" />
                    <col class="con0" />
                    <col class="con1" />
                    <col class="con0" />
                    <col class="con1" />
                     <col class="con0" />
                     <col class="con1" />
                      <col class="con0" />

                </colgroup>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="head0">#</th>
                        <th class="head1">Booking From</th>
                        <th class="head0">Pickup Postcode</th>
                        <th class="head1">Phone</th>
                        <th class="head0">Pickup Time</th>
                        <th class="head1">Pickup Date</th>
                         <th class="head0">Status</th>
                        <th class="head1">&nbsp;</th>
                        <th class="head0">&nbsp;</th>
                        <th class="head1">&nbsp;</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="head0">#</th> 
                        <th class="head1">Booking From</th>
                        <th class="head0">Pickup Postcode</th>
                        <th class="head1">Phone</th>
                        <th class="head0">Pickup Time</th>
                        <th class="head1">Pickup Date</th>
                         <th class="head0">Status</th>
                        <th class="head1">&nbsp;</th>
                         <th class="head0">&nbsp;</th>
                          <th class="head1">&nbsp;</th>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
                <tbody>
                   <? if(count($temp)==0) { ?>
                   <tr>
                                <td colspan="14" align="center"><span style="color: red; font-weight: bold;">No records found.</span></td>
                              </tr>
                     <? } else { ?>
                      <? foreach($temp as $k=>$r) { ?>
                    <tr class="gradeX">
                         <td class="center"><?=$r['id']?> </td>

                         <td class="center"><?=$r['booking_from']?></td>
                        <td class="center"><?= $r['picuppostcode'] ?></td>
                        <td class="center"><?=$r['phone']?></td>
                        <td class="center"><? $time = explode(',',$r['picuptime']); ?>
                                <?= $time[0] ?>hrs <?= $time[1] ?> mnts</td>
                        <td class="center"><?=$r['picupdate']?></td>

                     <?php if($r['status']=="New"){?>
                        <td class="center"  title="New" >
                      <img src="images/bluedot.png" alt="new" /></td>

                        <?php  } elseif($r['status']=="Cancelled") { ?>

                         <td class="center" title="Cancelled">
                      <img src="images/reddot.png"  /></td>

                       <?php  } elseif($r['status']=="Confirmed") { ?>

                         <td class="center" title="Confirmed">
                      <img src="images/yellowdot.png"  /></td>


                       <?php  } elseif($r['status']=="Confirmed Operator") { ?>

                        <td class="center" title="Confirmed Operator">
                      <img src="images/greendot.png"  /></td>

                         <?php  } elseif($r['status']=="") { ?>

                          <td class="center">No status</td>

                          <?php  } elseif($r['status']=="Posponend") { ?>
                           <td class="center" title="Posponend" >
                           <img src="images/blackdot.png" />
                           </td>


                           <?php  } elseif($r['status']=="Pending") { ?>
                           <td class="center" title="Pending">
                           <img src="images/browndot.jpg" />
                           </td>

                      <?php } ?>

                    <td class="center"><a href="ajax/tabledata.php?id=<?=$r['id']?>" class="toggle">Quick View</a></td>
                    <td class="center"><a href="Map.php?id=<?=$r['id']?>" class="toggle">Show Map</a></td> 

                   <td> 
                   <select name="actionuser" id="actionuser"  class="actionuser">
                   <option value="">--Actions--</option>
                   <option value="<?php echo $r['id']; ?>" class="quickview">Quick View</option>
                   <option value="showmap"> Show Map</option>
                   <option value="dispatchjob"> Dispatch job </option>

                   </select>
                   <input type="hidden" name="userid" class="userid" id="userid" value="<?=$r['id']?>" />

                  <!-- <input type="text" name="id" id="userid" value=<?php echo $_r['id'] ?>  />   --> 
                      </td>


                    </tr>
                    <!--<tr id="temp" class="gradeX"> </tr>-->


                    <? } ?>
                    <? } ?>

                    </tbody>
            </table>
            <div id="temp" class="toggledata"> </div>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="mainright">
        <div class="mainrightinner">

            <div class="widgetbox uncollapsible">
                <div class="title"><h2 class="chat"><span>Online Drivers</span></h2></div>
                <div class="widgetcontent padding0">
                    <!--<div class="chatsearch">
                        <input type="text" name="" value="Search" />
                    </div>-->

             <ul class="contactlist" id="driver">
      <li class="online new"><a href="#"><img src="images/avatar.png" alt="" /><span><?= $drv['name'] ?></span></a></li>
         </ul>


                    <!--<div class="chatbottom">
                        <a href="#">+ Add Contact</a>
                    </div>-->


                </div><!--widgetcontent-->
            </div><!--widgetbox-->

        </div><!--mainrightinner-->
    </div>


    <?php include("inc/footer.php"); ?>

    </div><!--maincontent-->
    </div><!--mainwrapperinner-->
</div><!--mainwrapper-->
<!-- END OF MAIN CONTENT -->
```

Comment: Oh man! Code is very unorganized. Can you please be little more clear and organized this will help people help you better.

Comment: only post code tht relates to issue at hand. Nobody needs to wade through your whole page! Not to mention you loosely mention `row` ...what row, based on what event? Put  little effort into asking concise questions that detail problem so it's easy to follow

Comment: sure don't need a bunch of php html parsing code either...if problem is client side, post raw html